# Cannot make persistant Insertion of a kernel object (debian) using Insmod

Tags: linux, bash, debian, linux-kernel, gpio

I'm trying to insert the [.]Ko (Kernel Object) file for the on-board GPIO into my Linux kernel which succeeds using the command **insmod < file-name.ko >** But when the OS/Device Reboots, the kernel no longer has the mod inserted (checking using lsmod). I have also tried placing it in */lib/modules/4.19.0-14-amd64/kernel/drivers/gpio* and running the "**sudo update-initramfs -u**" to update boot init but didn't work.

Is there any way to insert a kernel module permanently (sustains reboot)?

*P.S. I don't want to use "@reboot insmod" in crontab.* Using a Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Comment: Cross posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386100/cannot-make-persistant-insertion-of-a-kernel-object-debian-using-insmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your module to the modules.d folder, and it'll get picked up by systemd at boot time.

so make a file called `/etc/modules-load.d/<featurename>.conf`
and let it contain

```
<modulename>
```

where  is the name of the .ko file without the .ko extension

you can get documentation for modules-load.d by typing `man modules-load.d` at your terminal